# Search tool for Safari

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, search

I'm using Keywurl now, but since Safari 5.0.1 there are also supported extensions for search. I'd like to add any search url format and assign it to a shortcut.

e.g. `g macbook air` is google "macbook air", `w ipod` is google "site:en.wikipedia.org ipod" etc.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: You like Opera huh? ;)

Comment: Yes, that's where I discovered this feature :)

Comment: I'd still like an answer from somebody using a Safari extension for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims), a Safari plugin (not to be confused with an extension), will do what you want and more and allow you to customize the experience.

Comment: Looks just like what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

I know what you want because I had that in Opera a long time ago, but then I switched to Mac full time and dropped Opera. Safari lacks in that aspect.

I don’t know if there’s a specific extension for that, but you might want to take a look at tools like [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) ($$) or [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) (Free).

I use Launchbar and I type ‘goo’ and then whatever I want to type and enter. I Have searches for StackOverflow, Wikipedia, Amazon, etc. You can add whatever you want.

After some time doing that, it becomes extremely much more natural, because you can invoke either of those from anywhere in the system. You just invoke Launchbar, goo + xxxxx and you’re done.

Give it a try, I believe is a much more natural workflow than having to find safari, going to the search box and typing there.

Comment: But often I am in my browser anyway, and want to open, say, amazon in a new tab, not a new window. Otherwise, good suggestion!

Comment: @michiel Oh but even if I’m in safari, invoking launchbar doesn’t disrupt my safari experience. I have it configured to always open new tabs in the same window. I use it *a lot* here at Apple.SE when I need to remember the URL of a program (example to answer your question) I’m typing here and I do this: ->cmd-space (LBar Comes), type: go(already knows it’s a google search), type whatever I want to search, press enter. Safari opens a new tab with the google results :)

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it out right now!